# How do I loop audio in a flash video?

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I'm making an animated presentation for a class and I need to have audio looping in the background of the presentation. So far I've figured out how to make it loop but the music stops at every point where I have stop(); - I'm thinking because the code affects the music too. How can I stop the presentation so that the text can be read but make sure the music keeps looping?

Thanks in advance, sorry if the answer is incredibly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your audio is embedded within the timeline, set the "Sync" property in the Properties panel to "Event"

Or, you can add the song with code, like so...

Set the linkage of the sound in the library to "Music"

And add this code to wherever you want the music to start:

```
import flash.media.Sound;

var music:Sound = new Music();
music.play();
```